# Divide a Tchart into equal parts and then draw rectangles on it in Firemonkey

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, c++builder, teechart

I have a simple program in `C++ builder` with `VCL` that i need to migrate to `Firemonkey`. In this application i need to draw on a `TChart`, but i don't know how to get it to work. My application is really simple; a user inputs data in a stringgrid and then the data is displayed in two different `TChart` by clicking two different buttons.
The first button click is to divide the `TChart` into equal parts (generally in two parts, but the user can divide the `TChart` into more than two parts). In the first example there is a column, with two long rectangles with texts, in it. In this example it's two rectangles with "CH PL".

[image]

The second button is supposed to draw on the same `TChart` this:

[image]

It's essentially two or more rectangles which go from the beginning of the chart until the end.

To make it simple i need to divide the `TChart` into two or more equal parts horizontally and then draw rectangles with texts on it, which is the simplest solution.

I'm really lost because by searching on the net i came across a similar problem by simply using the `TChart.AfterDraw()` method, but I don't know how to use it, it's not really clear.

The drawing are generated once the user clicks a button, else there should be nothing.

My method for drawing so far:

```
void __fastcall TForm1::rbComprChange()
{
Series5->Clear(); //used for clearing the series to regenerate them from the user input

 for(int i=0;i<StringGrid1->RowCount;i++)
   {
Series5->AddGantt(StrToDate(StringGrid1->Cells[4][i]),StrToDate(StringGrid1->Cells[5][i]),i,StringGrid1->Cells[1][i]);
 Series5->NextTask->Value[i]=i;
    }
      // How and where should i draw these rectangles?!
     }
```

Can someone guide me or explain to me how to do that either in C++ Builder or Delphi.